# How to interpret thyristor's minimum load current?

Tags: photodiode, thyristor

I want to switch on/off a variable resistive load of 1mA to 150mA at 500VAC with a microcontroller.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRAJmf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The chip `CPC1972` looks very promising ([datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1807271222_IXYS-CPC1972GSTR_C150430.pdf)). However, the datasheet gives a lower limit for load current as `5mA`. I don't understand how to interpret this information.

(1) Does it mean that I cannot configure the variable resistance to let a `1mA` sine wave through it? In other words, is it possible to fix my POT to `500kOhm` and obtain a `1mA` current passing through the circuit?

(2) Or is this to do with latching as given in [this document](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an303-thyristors-and-triacs-latching-current-stmicroelectronics.pdf)? If so, where I learn more about on this topic?

Comment: It's 2. It won't latch below that.

Comment: @DKNguyen, so the circuit shown in the question delivers `1mA` when I set the POT to `500kOhms`. Right?

Comment: 1mA RMS, but the thyristor doesn't care about RMS. It cares about instantaneous current. So 1mA RMS as a sine wave is a sine wave that takes on values between -1.4AmA and 1.4mA

Comment: Yes. May be I am not explaining properly. My doubt is: 1mA RMS => 1.4mA peak can be achieved using the circuit shown in the question, Right?

Comment: Yes. Assuming your pot can handle 600VAC. And is safe to get close to it, let alone touch the knob while energized.

Comment: @DKNguyen, yes, The POT will be touched under no power condition. The safety mechanism mechanically disconnects before we can lay our hands on the POT.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum holding current at 25°C is 5mA, typical is 0.3mA.

If you want to ensure the opto-triac stays on, and your temperature range is wide, assume more like 15mA (typical curve below from the similar [MOC3031](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/MOC3031M-195882.pdf) datasheet).

[image]

Comment: Datasheet contains both holding current and minimum load  current. So, they must be two different parameters for the chip. Right?

https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1807271222_IXYS-CPC1972GSTR_C150430.pdf

Comment: As I said, I think it is typical vs. limit.